# how to use placeholder in tensorflow in below case

Tags: python, tensorflow

For the below code, can I use placeholder for the n, and pass the n by feeding?
I am quite new to tensorflow.

```
n = int(input("Enter an integer: "))

one=tf.constant(1)
#increase
increasing_value=tf.Variable(0,name="increasing_value")
increasing_op=tf.assign_add(increasing_value,one)

#sum
sumvalue=tf.Variable(0,name="sumvalue")
sum_op=tf.assign_add(sumvalue,increasing_value)

init=tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    for _ in range (n):
        session.run(increasing_op)
        session.run(sum_op)
    print(session.run(sumvalue))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
n = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name='n')

fedvalue = session.run( n , feed_dict = { n : 10 })
for _ in range ( fedvalue ):
    session.run(increasing_op)
    session.run(sum_op)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replicate your code in TensorFlow with a `tf.while_loop`.:

```
import tensorflow as tf

n = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
increasing_value = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
sum_value = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)

def loop_body(i, increasing_value, sum_value):
    increased_value = increasing_value + 1
    return i + 1, increased_value, sum_value + increased_value

i = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
_, increasing_value, sum_value = tf.while_loop(
    lambda i, _, __: i < n,
    loop_body,
    [i, increasing_value, sum_value])

with tf.Session() as session:
    for x in range(10):
        print(session.run(sum_value, feed_dict={n: x}))
```

Output:

```
0
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
```

However, TensorFlow loops are generally slow, and you should try to find a vectorial way of doing your computation (that is, express it as operations over arrays of values and reductions). In your particular case, your code is just computing [1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ⋯](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), which is simply `(n * (n + 1)) / 2`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

n = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
sum_value = (n * n + n) // 2

with tf.Session() as session:
    for x in range(10):
        print(session.run(sum_value, feed_dict={n: x}))
```

Output:

```
0
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
```